# Get Authentication error when put object to Azure storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-authentication

I am using java to make a REST Api call to Azure, put an object to its storage.
I did this successfully last week but now its now working for some reasons.
The error message is as below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:a15f2626-0001-004f-778c-f34383000000 Time:2017-07-02T23:43:20.2826278Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>The Date header in the request is incorrect.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
 </Error>
```

I don't think this is caused by the incorrect time stamp because the "Date" field and the response time are within 15 minutes. The "Date" field in the header is Sun, 2 Jul 2017 23:38:04 GMT
Here are my java code to generate the token and send the request.

```
 public void putObject(String blobName) {
    try {
        URL restServiceURL = new URL(getCallAddress() + "/" + blobName);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) restServiceURL.openConnection();

        Calendar cd = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", Locale.US);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = sdf.format(cd.getTime());

        httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        try {
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httpConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(getFile().length()); //set output size to avoid out of memory error

      try {
        String token = createToken(blobName, date);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "SharedKey " + Azure_AccountName + ":" + token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot get token");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(getFile().length()));
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date",date);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(getFile());
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        OutputStream out = httpConnection.getOutputStream();
        out.write(buffer);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (code != 201 && code != 200) {
            log.error(code + httpConnection.getResponseMessage());
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Put object failed");
        }
        httpConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }
}

private String createToken(String blobName, String date) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String signature = "PUT\n\n\n" + getFile().length() + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:" + date +
            "\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11\n" + "/" + Azure_AccountName + "/" + Azure_BucketName + "/" + blobName;
    SecretKey secreteKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(KEY), "HmacSHA256");
    Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance(secreteKey.getAlgorithm());
    sha256HMAC.init(secreteKey);
    byte[] digest = sha256HMAC.doFinal(signature.getBytes("UTF8"));
    return new String(Base64.encode(digest));
}
```

Comment: Why not directly use Azure Storage SDK for Java? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage) It's much easier than writing REST API calls by yourself.

Comment: I may not be able to use the SDK. Can you see any problems inside my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could refer to the code below if you haven't solved this Authentication error:

```
public class PutTest {

    private static final String account = <your account name>;
    private static final String key = <your account key>;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        File file = new File(<your file path>);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(<your file path>);

        String urlString = "https://" + account + ".blob.core.windows.net/<your container>/<your file name e.g:test.txt>";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
        getFileRequest(connection, account, key,  file.length());
        // connection.connect();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        out.write(buffer);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Response message : " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        System.out.println("Response code : " + connection.getResponseCode());

        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (connection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getErrorStream())));
        } else {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
        }
        System.out.println("Response body : " + br.readLine());
    }

    public static void getFileRequest(HttpURLConnection request, String account, String key, long length)
            throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String date = fmt.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " GMT";
        String stringToSign = "PUT\n" + "\n" // content encoding
                + "\n" // content language
                +length+"\n"// content length
                + "\n" // content md5
                +"\n" // content type
                + "\n" // date
                + "\n" // if modified since
                + "\n" // if match
                + "\n" // if none match
                + "\n" // if unmodified since
                + "\n" // range
                + "x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob" + "\n" 
                + "x-ms-date:" + date + "\n"
                + "x-ms-version:2015-02-21"+"\n" // headers
                + "/" + account + request.getURL().getPath(); // resources
        System.out.println("stringToSign : " + stringToSign);
        String auth = getAuthenticationString(stringToSign);
        request.setRequestMethod("PUT");

        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-date", date);
        request.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2015-02-21");
        request.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length));

    }

    private static String getAuthenticationString(String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key), "HmacSHA256"));
        String authKey = new String(Base64.encode(mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        String auth = "SharedKey " + account + ":" + authKey;
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've solved this problem. I used a different  Base64 package by mistake, though they had same name...They were both called Base64.